# Confusion in Applying Gauss Divergence Theorem.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Evaluate $\displaystyle \iint \vec{F}\cdot ds$ where $\vec{F}= 3x\hat{i} + 2y\hat{j} -5z\hat{k}$ and $S$ is the portion of the $y = x^2 + z^2$ that lies behind $y =1$ oriented in the direction of positive y -axis

I am trying to solve this with the help of Gauss theorem.

So, if I consider the disc $S_2 = (x^2 + z^2 = 1)$  along with $S_1 = (y = x^2 + z^2)$ then surface is closed, so Gauss theorem is applicable on  $S = S_1 \cup S_2$

Now, $\displaystyle\iint F\cdot ds =  \int \operatorname{div}F \,\mathrm{dv}$

But $\nabla\cdot F= 0$ this gives,

$$\iint_{S_2} F\cdot ds + \iint_{S_1} F\cdot ds = 0$$

Now, for $S_2$  outward normal Vector = $\hat{j}$

So, $\displaystyle\iint_{S_1} F\cdot ds  = -\iint (2y)\cdot dx dz$

Solving the integral gives $2\pi$

therefore, $\displaystyle\iint_{S_1} F\cdot ds = -2\pi$

However , answer given to me is $2\pi$ I do not understand why I am getting an extra negative sign.

Can someone please tell my mistake ?

Comment: Does the orientation prescribed in the problem statement match the outward orientation you assigned from the solid?

Answer (score 1):

When you closed it off with $S_2$, the $S_1$ with its normal pointing in the positive $y$-direction is the *inward* normal.  So there is an extra negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should vary with the direction of normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ on surface $S_1$.

If the normal vector direction $\mathbf{n}$ is negative $y$-axis(i.e. the angle is smaller than $\frac{\pi}{2}$), then the normal vector of $S_2$ is pointed to positive $y$-axis. Apply Gauss divergence theorem, the result
$$\iint_{S_1}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S=0-\iint_{S_2}\mathbf{F}\cdot(0,1,0)\ \mathrm{d}S=-2\pi$$

If the normal vector is of inner direction i.e. the angle between positive $y$-axis is smaller than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then the normal vector of $S_2$ should be $(0,-1,0)$ to make the whole surfaces closed.
$$\iint_{S_1}\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}\ \mathrm{d}S=-0-\iint_{S_{2}}\mathbf{F}\cdot(0,-1,0)\ \mathrm{d}S=2\pi$$